# Change microphone voice using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, electron

I would like to replicate the [Clownfish](https://clownfish-translator.com/voicechanger/) app in Electron.

I need to use NodeJS to transmit an audio file to the microphone, on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Is there any way to transmit audio through the user's microphone

Comment: Do you mean transmit an audio file to the speaker?

Comment: @jfriend00 No, I really mean transmit a file to the microphone

Comment: And, what is a microphone supposed to do with a file you send it?

Comment: @jfriend00 transmit that file. So if I'm using Skype for example, the other participants will hear the contents of that file

Comment: I rather doubt you want to send that audio file to the microphone.  Microphones are a source of audio, not a destination for audio.  You want to send it to the app as though it came from the microphone.  How to do that would be app-specific.

Comment: @jfriend00 But I would indeed like to do it to the microphone such that it would work with any app listening to the microphone, and not do something specific per app

Comment: Sure you'd "like" to do it that way.  But, a microphone doesn't work that way - it's a source of audio, not a destination for audio.  You need to be looking for a different way to do this.